# How do I fix my PHP code not being able to get array values correctly from JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am working on a PHP project for chores, and I am at the last part of the project. I just need to finish the 'Alternate Chore' functionality so that the user can input an alternate chore instead of the regular daily chore. And when I created the script, I ran into it using the wrong arrays or variables, because it wasn't showing the correct details. It was checking if the alternate chore instead of the chore title was in the daily chores, when it should be checking the chore title.

So then I thought 'oh silly me' and I went ahead and I inverted the two variables in this space:
(All the variables have been defined above somewhere in my code, so don't worry about that)

```
$alternateChoresFile = $person . "-alternate.json";
if (file_exists($alternateChoresFile)) {
    $alternateChores = json_decode(file_get_contents($alternateChoresFile), true);
    if (isset($alternateChores[$day])) {
        foreach ($alternateChores[$day] as $altIndex => $altChore) { 
            if (in_array(*$altChore*, $chores[$day])) {
                $completedData[$day][array_search(*$altChore*, $chores[$day])] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

italicized is the values I changed to be inverted, but I turned up with nothing. After that I tried different variations of the variables, still nothing. If you could help me with this, that would be great. Thank you

My JSON code is below:

```
{
    "Sunday":{"test":"alternate chore for test"},
    "Saturday":{"test":"also an alternate chore"},
    "Thursday":{"test":"wow alternate",
                "wow":"alternate chore for the chore 'wow'"
                }
}
```

As you can see there are days, and there are the chore the alternate chore is replacing, and the alternate chore itself.

Comment: We can't see the data you're working with. Please [edit] your question with a relevant JSON sample, and a sample of the expected output you want your code to produce

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? How is this problem related to JSON itself?

Comment: It's still not very clear what the output should be. Please provide a sample as requested previously, then there's no ambiguity